# Individual-level open geographic data on international human trafficking

Tags: data-request, crime

I was actually trying to find some open source data on human trafficking. Basically, I was looking for any individual level data where say an individual was picked up by some law enforcement agency and then ask for their country of origin. I believe the International Organization on Migration has data like this, but they don't release it.

I have been looking around and there only seems to be summary statistics given at the country level. I was hoping that someone might be able to direct me towards a good source. I am a grad student in statistics, so was hoping to do some meaningful analysis.

**Update:**

The closest thing I have been able to find so far is some data from the European Union. There is a report from the European union based upon input from the legal agencies in different member countries. Here is the report [link](https://ec.europa.eu/anti-trafficking/sites/antitrafficking/files/eurostat_report_on_trafficking_in_human_beings_-_2015_edition.pdf). On page 36 there is table 3 which provides info on the human trafficking arrests from each nation. So this data at least shows the country of arrest and the country of origin for the victim.

[image]
The problem with this data is that it does not show the path of each victim, so I don't know the routes.

Thus, I am still searching for additional info.